# File transfer using libpurple

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, instant-messaging, pidgin, libpurple

I'm kind of stuck trying to code an example of file transfer using libpurple.

My first try was to reuse the nullclient example from the libpurple/examples source directory and call serv_send_file. That seems to compile and execute fine but then nothing happens in the side of the receiver (he doesn't get the file transfer request).

Pointers and/or partial code (in any language) are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself. I was making a bunch of mistakes, corrected those and uploaded a full working example [here](https://github.com/fabianp/libpurple-examples/blob/master/send_file.c). Things I've learned from this:

- call the file transfer from the "buddy-signed-on" signal and never from the "signed-on" signal.
- There seems to be three ways to do this: using purple_xfer_* , serv_send_file, and the one I used, prpl->send_file.

Hope this helps other people that are, as me, learning libpurple.

Comment: A [related question](/questions/77992302) -- how would I send a message to a chatroom?